# How to set autoflush=false in HBase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have this code that saves to HBase HTABLE. The expected behavior is that the table will push the commits or "flush" the puts to hbase for each partition.

NOTE: This is the updated code

```
rdd.foreachPartition(p => {
  val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(HTABLE))
  val mutator = connection.getBufferedMutator(TableName.valueOf(HTABLE))

  p.foreach(row => {
    val hRow = new Put(rowkey)
    hRow.addColumn....
    // use table.exists instead of table.checkAndPut (in favor of BufferedMutator's flushCommits)
    val exists = table.exists(new Get(rowkey))
    if (!exists) {
      hRow.addColumn...
    }
    mutator.mutate(hRow)
  })
  table.close()
  mutator.flush()
  mutator.close()
})
```

In HBase 1.1, HTable is deprecated and there's no flushCommits() available in org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table.

Replacing BufferedMutator.mutate(put) is ok for normal puts, but mutator does not have any checkAndPut similar to Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set autoFlush to false see section 11.7.4
in http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/perf.writing.html

Comment: Thanks Arnon. Do you know how to set the autoflush=false in HBase 1.1 Table? Since HTable is deprecated there

Comment: in HBase 1.1 you should use BufferedMutator instead - see slides 42 oneward here http://www.slideshare.net/enissoz/meet-hbase-10

Comment: I tried replacing Puts with BufferedMutator.mutate(put), but mutator does not have any checkAndPut similar to Table

Comment: right -because you can't do that in a buffered manner because you're working with a batch and there's no atomicity for that in HBase

Comment: Thank you Arnon. I used BufferedMutator for flushCommits :)

Answer (score 7):

In the new API, `BufferedMutator`is used.

You could change `Table t = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("foo"))` to `BufferedMutator t = connection.getBufferedMutator(TableName.valueOf("foo"))`. And then change `t.put(p);` to `t.mutate(p);`

It works for me!

There is little information about that when I was searching, even in the official document. Hope my answer is helpful, and someone could update the document.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to do anything since you `DONT` want to buffer puts at Client side. `By default, HBase client will not buffer the PUTS at client side.`

Explicit calls to flushCommits() is only required when the client handling when to send data to HBase RegionServers.